# Spring `JpaRepository` to be used only in test scope

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, execution-time

I have a `JpaRepository`, that looks like

```
@Repository
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityType, Integer> {
    // Methods
}
```

which could possibly have queries that would run for long, in which case I need to enforce a timeout. I have successfully added the timeout-related configuration (the connection pool being used is `Druid`, if that matters) and now I want to test it in a unit test. I am using the following method in my `JpaRepository<T, ID>` interface.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT benchmark(:count, MD5('3094803'))", nativeQuery = true)
void run(@Param("count") Long count);
```

This method runs successfully and demonstrates the expected behavior. However, given that this method will run longer as the value given to parameter `count` becomes larger, having this in the production code, just for the sake of testing the timeouts, bothers me to my core, as this might end up being a vulnerability that could be leveraged to launch a denial attack.

So to the question, is some way I can use this exact method in my test scope, without having that going in the production code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's not that complicated. Given that this project is running on Spring, I can have an extension of the above repository in my test sources, as follows.

```
package com.project.package.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TimedCustomRepository extends CustomRepository {
    @Query(value = "SELECT benchmark(:count, MD5('3094803'))", nativeQuery = true)
    void run(@Param("count") Long count);
}
```

As I have JUnit4, I can have a test class which will run on Spring boot, like follows.

```
package om.project.package.repo;

import com.github.database.rider.spring.api.DBRider;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DBRider(dataSourceBeanName = "primaryDataSource") //Data source wiring; Not that important.
public class TransactionHistoryJpaRepoTest {

    @Autowired //---(1)
    private TimedCustomRepository timedCustomRepository;

    @Test(expected = JpaSystemException.class)
    public void whenQueryTimeoutOccurs() {
        timedCustomRepository.run(100000000L);
    }
}
```

The property at `(1)` will be wired using the repository bean which we have created above, and this test will execute as expected. Given the bean `TimedCustomRepository` extends `CustomRepository`, the data source configuration and everything will be the same. Most importantly, since this method with a long running query is now only on the test scope, it will not have any impact beyond the test scope.